# Licensing for VF page in managed package

Tags: visualforce, managed-package

I have a VF page to be included in the Account detail screen using the standard pagelayout feature. The page is to be provided as part of a managed package via the appExchange.

If the package is installed and the VF page is added to the page layout and the current user isn't licensed for the package what will they see? Do I need to handle the status where the user isn't licensed via the `UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed('namespace')` and show a 'failure' message?

I know the admins can create different page layouts and only include for profiles/users with access but I'd like this to be handled automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to check anything. The platform will automatically deny access to the page before your constructor even has a chance to execute. They will see a simple message stating that they do not have permission to view the page; this message cannot be intercepted or overridden.